# Unable to send response back to the website in this case pancake swap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, blockchain, metamask

So, I am making an extension just like metamask. I am using the metamask provider library to inject the provider into the webpage.

```
import { WindowPostMessageStream } from "@metamask/post-message-stream";
import { initializeProvider } from "@metamask/providers/dist/initializeInpageProvider";

// contexts
const CONTENT_SCRIPT = "contentscript";
const INPAGE = "inpage";

// setup background connection
const metamaskStream = new WindowPostMessageStream({
  name: INPAGE,
  target: CONTENT_SCRIPT,
});

initializeProvider({
  connectionStream: metamaskStream,
});
```

This above code is the inpage code that was executed using the following command

```
 chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([
      {
        id: "contentscript",
        matches: ["file://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        js: ["inpage-bundle.js"],
        runAt: "document_start",
        world: "MAIN",
        allFrames: true,
      },
    ]);
```

The above code is in background.js.

Now the problem is that I am receiving the JSON RPC request from the pancakeswap website and handling it using json-rpc-engine library.

After getting the response I am not able to send the response back to the website to proceed further with the connection.

I tried posting the messing from window object to the window or `metamaskStream.write(data)` but nothing seems to work.

This is my content script file

```
/*global chrome*/
import { WindowPostMessageStream } from "@metamask/post-message-stream";
import { metamaskStream, provider } from "./inpage";
const Buffer = require("safe-buffer").Buffer;

const isManifestV3 = true;
// contexts
const CONTENT_SCRIPT = "contentscript";
const INPAGE = "inpage";

const setupPageStreams = () => {
  // the transport-specific streams for communication between inpage and background
  const pageStream = new WindowPostMessageStream({
    name: CONTENT_SCRIPT,
    target: INPAGE,
  });

  if (isManifestV3) {
    pageStream.on("data", async ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        if (data.method === "eth_requestAccounts") {
          const finalResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
              { type: "JSON-RPC", payload: data },
              (response) => {
                console.log(response, "response");
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                  reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                } else if (response && response.type === "JSON-RPC") {
                  resolve(response.payload);
                } else {
                  reject(new Error("Invalid response received"));
                }
              }
            );
          });

          if (finalResponse) {
            const responseToSend = {
              ...finalResponse,
              namespace: "global",
              code: 0,
              message: "SUCCESS",
            };

            console.log("finalResponse", responseToSend);
            pageStream.write(responseToSend);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

/**
 * Initializes two-way communication streams between the browser extension and
 * the local per-page browser context. This function also creates an event listener to
 * reset the streams if the service worker resets.
 */
const initStreams = () => {
  setupPageStreams();
};

const start = () => {
  initStreams();
};

start();
```

Comment: The inpage is running the MAIN word so that provider can be injected and the content script is running in context of the extension. I am able to receive messages from the inpage and send messages to the inpage but the panckake swap page is not repsonding, I am not sure what could e the issue